# Failing to resolve solidity versions even though the intersection exists

Tags: solidity, version-pragma

I am writing my contracts in solidity version defined as ^0.8.0. I want to use Uniswap router interface, which is using >=0.7.5. Why is the compilation failing even though a compiler version ^0.8.0 should fulfill both requirements?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^ or >= accept all the newer minor changes, but the major update will fail this condition:

^0.8.0 would accept 0.8.1, 0.8.2, ..., 0.8.x, but 0.9.0 will not be accepted.

>=0.7.5 will accept all 0.7.x versions, but 0.8.0 will fail.

Look up [Semantic Versioning (Semver)](https://semver.org/).

Comment: I tried putting the >=0.7.5 verison to [online semver checker](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/%3E%3D0.7.5/0.8.0) and it says that version 0.8.0 fits the condition 

It also seems to be the case according to [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/KiTOycVbgcI?t=255).

Comment: That is because Solidity is following a different Semver system, where 0.x.0 is a major, and 0.0.x is a minor update (as in, 0.0.x updates bring in new non-breaking features, but 0.x.0 updates bring in some breaking features that cause incompatibility).  Solidity docs on that: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/installing-solidity.html#versioning

Comment: That clears my confusion. Thanks a ton